# Adding HourGlass Cursor in Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am trying to add HourGlass cursor in my code.I tried this code
session:set-wait-state('HourGlass').

But I did not get HourGlass Cursor.Please help me to get cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the hourglass in Windows Vista or later; you get the round circle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
session:set-wait-state("general").
```

Comment: I've used this code quite a lot, always gives me an hourglass. I'd check the custom cursor settings on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

to turn the hour glass cursor on:

```
SESSION:SET-WAIT-STATE("wait":U).
```

to turn it back off:

```
SESSION:SET-WAIT-STATE("":U).
```